# SHA1 producing different result in Objective-C and C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, sha1

I'm having trouble with hashing some string with SHA1 : C# and Objective C are producing a different result.

Objective C :

```
- (void) hashSHA1:(NSString*)input salt:(NSString*)salt
{
    const char *cstr = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",input, salt] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    NSLog("%@ : %@", input,output);
}
```

Output :

```
[self hashSHA1:@"F66791B5-33F1-49BB-AAA9-1D7A1CE51752" salt:@"salt"];
//Show : F66791B5-33F1-49BB-AAA9-1D7A1CE51752 : 435ba79fde87c45150fd053ca43ecce92fac54d3
```

C# :

```
static void HashSha1(string uid, string salt)
{
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uid + salt);
    var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var b in hash)
    {
        sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", uid,sb.ToString());
}
```

Output :

```
HashSha1("F66791B5-33F1-49BB-AAA9-1D7A1CE51752", "salt");
//Show : F66791B5-33F1-49BB-AAA9-1D7A1CE51752 : 0853829f9df35d4171b7aff44ed62f0747523a3f
```

Did I miss something here ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you verify if `data` contains the same value in both cases before the call to the hash function ?

Comment: Indeed ! data value didn't change after calling the sha1.ComputeHash(data) !

Comment: No, I meant if `data` contains the same value in both pieces of code, not before and after the call to the hash function

Comment: Just to be clear: you are calling the hash functions with the `data` variable as parameter in both cases. Not the uid, input or salt variables. What I want to know is if the `data` variable has the same value just before the call to hash functions, and this in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this line of Objective-C code, and admiting to not knowing much about Obj-C, shouldn't this line:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];
```

read:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:strlen(cstr)];
```

?

Comment: Thanks. You just saved my day mrlucmorin ! But you should change cstr.length to strlen(cstr)

Comment: Hehehe, just confirming my ignorance of Obj-C. I modified my post accordingly. Cheers

Comment: No problem mrlucmorin ! Merci beaucoup :)