# SHA1 hash difference between c# windows store app and Objective-c iOS

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, windows-store-apps, sha1

My Windows Store app on the Surface pro uses the SHA1 to send a hashed password to the server. I wanted to do the same thing for the iOS app but I get different results and I just don't know why.

I tried with different encoding (NSASCII UTF8 UniCode) when converting NSStrings to cString but to no prevail.

**c# Windows Store App - Surface pro**

```
/// <summary>
    /// Literal copy of the values from web config machinekey
    /// </summary>
    const String validationKey = "6DB51F17C529AD3CABEC50B3C89CB21F4F1422F58A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA146511891C1BAF47F8D29401E3400267682B202B7DA146511891C1BAF47F8D29401E3";

    public static string HmacSha1(string baseString)
    {
        var crypt = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA1");
        var buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(baseString));
        var keyBuffer = Windows.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(HexToByte(validationKey));
        var key = crypt.CreateKey(keyBuffer);
        var sigBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Sign(key, buffer);
        string signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(sigBuffer);
        return signature;
    }

    //
    // HexToByte
    //   Converts a hexadecimal string to a byte array. Used to convert encryption
    // key values from the configuration.
    //
    private static byte[] HexToByte(string hexString)
    {
        byte[] returnBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < returnBytes.Length; i++)
            returnBytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        return returnBytes;
    }
```

**Objective-c iOS**

```
//Hash password
NSString *secret = @"6DB51F17C529AD3CABEC50B3C89CB21F4F1422F58A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA146511891C1BAF47F8D29401E3400267682B202B7DA146511891C1BAF47F8D29401E3";
NSString *data = password;
const char *cKey = [secret cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString *signature = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];


NSString *clientPassword = signature;
```

Comment: From your codes, C# uses Unicode while Obj-C uses ASCII... It's normal to produce different results.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As stated I tried different encoding. This **cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding** still gets a different result alas. Can it have something to do with the HexToByte in c#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SHA1 producing different result in Objective-C and C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583387/sha1-producing-different-result-in-objective-c-and-c-sharp)

Comment: @Raptor I have seen this post you marked as duplicate. Please take a look at the **difference in c# code** (concerning a Windows Store App). This is what I have to work with, and have to make the Objective-c code produce the same results. I any case thank you for looking into this question.

Comment: Provide the C# result. Since all the input characters are ASCII it =makes no difference if you use `NSASCIIStringEncoding` or `NSUTF8StringEncoding` but use the `NSUTF8StringEncoding` unless there is a specific need for another encoding.

Comment: @zaph c# signature output **qxUa2lk3q5rvJ/7bCJ75GBstoL0=** when inputting password **Welkom123**. I also came to that conclusion. Yet the c# code uses the Unicode encoding in this line **var buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(baseString));**

Comment: There seems to be more going on than just an HMac-SHA1. Provide hex dumps of the following: `buffer`, `keyBuffer`, `key`, `sigBuffer`. It is also possible that the `validationKey` and `baseString` are in UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

So some genius helped me figure it out. In c# code the password is encoded with Unicode as can be seen in this line:

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(baseString)
```

That means I should have changed this the NSASCII encoding line in Objective-C to:

```
const char *cPassword = [password cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

Now comes something tricky. Unicode encodes a string like 'Welkom123' like this: `W/0e/0l/0k/0o/0m/01/02/03/0`. That means I can't use `strlen(cData)` to determine the length of cData because it will stop counting when encountering `/0`, so the length has been wrong the whole time. I had to replace `strlen(cData)` with `(password.length * 2)`.

But even then the outcome was still not right. The key had to become Hexadecimal data just like in the c# code. Then the NSData should be used to create the CCHmac. This code turns the NSString to NSData with hexadecimal values:

```
int len = (int)([inputString length] / 2);    // Target length
unsigned char *buf = malloc(len);
unsigned char *whole_byte = buf;
char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};

int i;
for (i=0; i < [inputString length] / 2; i++) {
    byte_chars[0] = [inputString characterAtIndex:i*2];
    byte_chars[1] = [inputString characterAtIndex:i*2+1];
    *whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
    whole_byte++;
}

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:len];
free( buf );
return data;
```

In the end the total code would look like this:

```
-(NSDictionary *)authenticateWithUsername:(NSString *)userName andPassword:(NSString *)password andSyncUrl:(NSString *)syncUrl
{
NSString *key = @"6DB51F17C529AD3CABEC50B3C89CB21F4F1422F58A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA146511891C1BAF47F8D29401E3400267682B202B7DA146511891C1BAF47F8D29401E3";
NSData *data = [self stringToHexData:key];
const char *cPassword = [password cStringUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA1, data.bytes, data.length, cPassword, (password.length * 2), cHMAC);
NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString *hashedPassword = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSString *clientPassword = hashedPassword;

// some code here left out for readability sake

return dict;
}

- (NSData *) stringToHexData:(NSString *)inputString
{
int len = (int)([inputString length] / 2);    // Target length
unsigned char *buf = malloc(len);
unsigned char *whole_byte = buf;
char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};

int i;
for (i=0; i < [inputString length] / 2; i++) {
    byte_chars[0] = [inputString characterAtIndex:i*2];
    byte_chars[1] = [inputString characterAtIndex:i*2+1];
    *whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
    whole_byte++;
}

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buf length:len];
free( buf );
return data;
}
```